# Constructor yields null - where to start?

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, testng

I am creating a set of TestNG tests in eclipse for existing code that supposedly validates certificates against a CRL.

In my test, I create a new class to provide validation functions, like this:

```
public void testRevokedCertificate() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedFileServer embeddedFileServer = new EmbeddedFileServer(CertificateResourceHelper.getResourcePath("."));
    embeddedFileServer.start();
    URL crlUrl = new URL("http://localhost:" + embeddedFileServer.getPort() + "/certs/" + "test_ca1.crl");
    CachingValidCrlProvider prov = new CachingValidCrlProvider(crlUrl, publicKey, 1, 2);
    assertNotNull(prov);
}
```

The constructor `CachingValidCrlProvider(URL, publicKey, int, int)` *always* returns `null`! This is a mystery to me, as the constructor does not look very special:

```
public CachingValidCrlProvider(URL crlUrl, PublicKey expectedPublicKey, int failedDownloadBackoffTimeInSeconds, int forcedCrlRefreshIntervalInSeconds) {
    System.out.println("Creating CachingValidCrlProvider (this is never displayed)");
    this.crlUrl = crlUrl;
    this.expectedPublicKey = expectedPublicKey;
    crlDownloadState = new CrlDownloadState(failedDownloadBackoffTimeInSeconds, forcedCrlRefreshIntervalInSeconds);
}
```

The first debug `println()` **is somehow never reached** since I cannot find the printed line in stdout. 
AFAIK, one of the few ways constructors may yield `null` is when a `static {}` block fails somewhere down the line. However, I do not see any (there is one such block in the codebase but not reachable in this scenario).

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: `new` operator (not constructor) cannot return null. It returns a new instance or it throws an exception. Make sure your test runner reports exceptions or catch and log the exception yourself.

Comment: That is weird since TestNG says: `java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)`

Comment: You asked "How do I troubleshoot?" The answer is: put try-catch(Throwable) around around the assignment and print the exception's stack trace.

Comment: Weird things like this are often caused by build problems that actually let you to run old cold instead of the one you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses. They helped me get to the root cause. As it turned out, there was a *mock* initialization of this class in another test (there are ~300 existing tests by other people in this codebase).

Because the code uses singletons extensively, my call to `new` did not actually change anything to the already-initialized object.

I found this thanks to your remarks and hints which made me look in different parts of the codebase, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Static Initialization Blocks are executed before anything else, So the code is reached, you just don't know it. I suggest you add a breakpoint in your static block, and use a debugger (included in eclipse or Intellij) to see when it fails. good luck.

Comment: Static _initialization_ block - the distinction is important.

Comment: Indead, it's fixed

Answer (score 1):

Quote from an answer here on StackOverflow by Jon Skeet:

> From section [15.9.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):
>
> > The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.
>
> So no, it can never return null.

A constructor in Java **CANNOT** return null. The only case your object can be null is if you didn't call the constructor, or the constructor raised an exception.

**EDIT**:

As for your code, the most probable possibility IMO is that the code doesn't stop on your `assertNotNull(prov)`, but never reaches it and instead crashes somewhere before. You should try using the debugger/more sysout.

Comment: I have seen that answer here on SO during my research prior to asking this question. If I did not see this with my own eyes I would not believe it. There is no exception, just the `null` object as a result.

Comment: @mvreijn As someone said in a comment, you could check that you're not executing old code -- in the end, your constructor cannot set your object at null. The only possibility would be that some thread in your code gets the instance you just created and delete it right after its creation.